# Python script unloading the data from Redshift without any file type in S3 bucket. Need CSV file format

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have csv file containing schema and table name (Format shared below). My task is to unload data from Redshift to S3 bucket in CSV file type. For this task I have below `python`  script and I have 2 IAM access. First IAM access to unload data from Redshift. 2nd IAM access to write the data to S3 bucket. The issue that I am facing is using below script, I am able to create folder in my S3 bucket, however instead of CSV file the file type is " -" in S3 bucket. I am not sure what is the possible reason ?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and effort!

*Note: I have millions of rows to unload from Redshift to S3 bucket.*

**CSV File containing schema and table name**

```
Schema;tables
mmy_schema;my_table
```

**Python Script**

```
import csv
import redshift_connector
import sys

CSV_FILE="Tables.csv"
CSV_DELIMITER=';'
S3_DEST_PATH="s3://..../"
DB_HOST="MY HOST"
DB_PORT=1234
DB_DB="MYDB"
DB_USER="MY_READ"
DB_PASSWORD="MY_PSWD"
IM_ROLE="arn:aws:iam::/redshift-role/unload data","arn:aws::iam::/write in bucket"

def get_tables(path):
    tables=[]
    with open (path, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader (file,delimiter=CSV_DELIMITER)
        header = next(csv_reader)
        if header != None:
            for row in csv_reader:
                tables.append(row)
    return tables

def unload(conn, tables, s3_path):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    for table in tables:
        print(f">{table[0]}.{table[1]}")
        try:
            query= f'''unload('select * from {table[0]}.{table[1]}' to '{s3_path}/{table[1]}/'
            iam_role '{IAM_ROLE}'
            CSV
            PARALLEL FALSE
            CLEANPATH;'''
            print(f"loading in progress")
            cur.execute(query)
            print(f"Done.")
        except Esception as e:
            print("Failed to load")
            print(str(e))
            sys.exit(1)
            
        cur.close()
        

def main():
    try:
        conn = redshift_connector.connect(
        host=DB_HOST,
        port=DB_PORT,
        database= DB_DB,
        user= DB_USER,
        password=DB_PASSWORD
        )
        
        tables = get_tables(CSV_FILE)
        unload(conn,tables,S3_DEST_PATH)
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't add file type suffixes on UNLOAD.  It should just end with the part number.  Yes, "parallel off" unloads can make multiple files.  If it is required that these file names end in ".csv" then your script will need to issue the S3 rename API calls (copy and delete).  This process should also check that the number of files and perform appropriate actions if needed.

Comment: Can you please guide with correct code needed ?I would like to create copy of table into S3 bucket in CSV file. I am little bit new to API calls. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing - are you confident that you will only get 1 file from the unload?  6.2GB is the default max file size.  If the data you are unloading is larger than this then you will get multiple files in S3.

Comment: As for moving the file from one file name to another (move) there are a number of posting on this - https://medium.com/plusteam/move-and-rename-objects-within-an-s3-bucket-using-boto-3-58b164790b78

Comment: ..correct I am not sure about file size that is why I set the PARALLEL to OFF.  The issue that I am facing is I am not getting file in CSV format as file type in S3 bucket. The filename is "000" with "-" as type in S3

Comment: "Parallel off" just just combines the data from each node into one stream coming from the leader node.  If this single stream of data produces more than 6.2GB of data then there will be more files - 000, 001, 002, ...  There is no way to get unload to produce a single file in all circumstances.

Comment: If cannot be assured that there will be less than 6.2GB data produced your code will need to account for this in some way.  This will be solution dependent - are multiple files ok or do they need to be combined?  If combined then what about the max S3 files size limit?  (5TB)

Comment: As for filename "000" this implies that your "table[1]" variable isn't set as "000" is what Redshift appends to the filename.  As for file type being '-' this is artificially being reported by whatever tool you are using to explore S3.  It just means that no file suffix has been set, or empty.  S3 just stores "things" and doesn't care about file naming conventions like suffixes.  It is important to remember that S3 is not a file system (it's an object store).  There are no "folders", just buckets and keys.  Interpreting '/' as a folder is just pretending what S3 would be like if it had folders

Comment: ..I am ok with multiple files. Thanks, that makes sense about Amazon bucket! I was wondering if there is a way to find and print  number of rows that were present in Redshift and number of rows transferred to  S3 bucket files ? Here is my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871056/counting-number-of-records-when-unloading-the-data-from-redshift-to-s3-using-pyt?noredirect=1&lq=1